# Polya-Szego inequality w.r.t. partial direction

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

Let $f\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and let $f^*$ be its symmetric deceasing rearragement. Then the Polya-Szego inequality tells us that $f^*$ is also in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and
$$\|\nabla f^*\|_2\leq \|\nabla f\|_2. $$

My question is as follows: Consider the domain $\Omega:=(0,1)\times \mathbb{R}^d$ and let $g$ be a function in $H^1(\Omega)$. For given $t\in(0,1)$ let $g^*(t,y)$ be the symmetric decreasing rearrangment of $g$ w.r.t. the direction of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then I would like to ask whether the following statements are true:

1. Is $g^*$ still an element in $H^1(\Omega)$? I think it is ok to say that $g$ has partial derivative along $\mathbb{R}^d$, but I don't know what happens in the $t$-direction.
2. Do we have the ineuqlaity $\|\nabla_{t,y}g^*\|_2\leq \|\nabla_{t,y}g\|_2$?

Thank you very much for your help!